# sparkcontext for local spark cluster

Tags: c#, apache-spark, mobius

Could someone please be so kind and tell me how to adapt the hdfs URIs in the following code so that they work against my local spark 'cluster'?

```
var lines = sparkContext.TextFile(@"hdfs://path/to/input.txt");  
// some more code
wordCounts.SaveAsTextFile(@"hdfs://path/to/wordcount.txt");
```

Comment: Spark local mode does not involve a cluster. Are you running a cluster (Standalone, YARN or Mesos) in the machine where you are trying to run Mobius-based Spark application?

Comment: Sure it doesn't. That's why I used inverted commas. I simply want to develop a console application in visual studio against my local spark before I deploy it in the future. Yes, I am trying to run a Mobius-based Spark application

Answer (score 0):

You can just define path location config parameter will get setup on sparkcontext so no need to add hdfs just like below should be fine to run application in yarn mode

```
var lines = sparkContext.TextFile("/path/to/input.txt");  
// some more code
wordCounts.SaveAsTextFile("/path/to/wordcount.txt");
```

or you can to explicitly define hdfs location as below

```
val lines =  sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://namenode:port/path/to/input.txt")
```

you can also define number of partitions which is optional

```
var lines = sparkContext.TextFile("/path/to/input.txt",[number of partitions]);
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) how do I parameterise the SparkContext to run against the local spark? (2) what would be the code if my file is here c:\war_and_peace.txt?